# Removing the default Context Menu when Editing a cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

In my DataGridView, when I am editing a textbox cell, and I right click I get the following default Context Menu:

[image: Dont want this!]

How can I disable this "feature" and instead have my own context Menu popup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this is what you asking about?  You can find the similar question using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266971/disable-datagridview-system-contextmenu) link.

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.ContextMenuStrip = myContextMenuStrip;
    }
```

Comment: Yea I saw that and implemented it incorrectly so I thought it was wrong.  ContextMenu and ContextMenuStrip work.